# How do you capture the output of a SQL Script run from .NET, including rows affected?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlconnection

Consider this simple SQL script:

```
PRINT N'Dropping CREATE_TABLE events from DatabaseLog table...'
DELETE FROM [dbo].[DatabaseLog] WHERE Event = N'CREATE_TABLE'
PRINT N'Dropping ALTER_TABLE events from DatabaseLog table...'
DELETE FROM [dbo].[DatabaseLog] WHERE Event = N'ALTER_TABLE'
PRINT N'Done!'
```

When run from SSMS, against AdventureWorks 2012, it gives this output:

```
Dropping CREATE_TABLE events from DatabaseLog table...

(70 row(s) affected)
Dropping ALTER_TABLE events from DatabaseLog table...

(117 row(s) affected)
Done!
```

How do I reproduce this in .NET, including the rows affected lines?

By hooking into the `InfoMessage` event on the `SqlConnection`, I get the output of the `PRINT` statements, but this doesn't include the rows affected lines. Ideally, I want to capture the output exactly as if it was run in SSMS.

Note: The script is user-supplied, so modifying the script to output the row counts manually is not an option.

Comment: what are you using to execute the commands? for the example you could have `SqlCommand` for each statement and then use [`ExectueNonQuery()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) method that returns rows affected

Comment: Currently, we're using `ExecuteNonQuery()` from SMO, in order to handle GO separators. Splitting the script into separate `SqlCommand`s is not an option, because that doesn't work if the script uses variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the right event to get the individual statement counts from! `StatementCompleted` on the individual `SqlCommand` fires multiple times, once for each statement that affects rows. So:

```cs
public static void ExecuteScript(string connectionString, string sql)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.InfoMessage += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
        conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.StatementCompleted += (sender, args) =>
                Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}({args.RecordCount} row(s) affected)");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

reproduces the output from SSMS, for the queries I've tries so far, which have included `CREATE TABLE`, `PRINT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, and `SELECT`.

Setting `FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors` to `true` is necessary, otherwise all the `InfoMessage` events appear at the end, rather than being correctly interleaved with `StatementCompleted` events. However, when `FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors` is set to `true`, `SqlException` will not be thrown if there are errors, so you must check each InfoMessage for errors (if the `Class` is set to > 10).

Comment: I found it too but you beat me to it :-) The secret sauce was FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors but note the onus is on you to identify errors rather than rely on try/catch.

Comment: Thanks, I would probably have missed that detail! I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery` should return the affected rows;

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [dbo].[DatabaseLog] WHERE Event = N'CREATE_TABLE'",conn);
int rowsAffected = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This only works if there is only a single statement. As I am not in control of the script, and indeed the script will usually contain multiple statements, this is not an option.

Comment: What value is returned if you have multiple statements. Did you try it ?

Comment: @Stormcloak, I would expect the cumulative row count for the entire batch to be returned.

Comment: Yes, it returns the total row count - 187, in the example I gave in the question.